# Retrieving eloquent api resource using keyby collection method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-resource

I have an end API point

```
users/{user}
```

now in User resource, I want to return

```
     public function toArray($request)
        {
            // return parent::toArray($request);

            return [
                'id' => $this->id,
                'name' => $this->name,
//                'comments' => $this->post->comments->keyBy('post_id')
                'comments' => new CommentCollection($this->post->comments->keyBy->post_id)

            ];
        }
```

CommentCollection class

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        // return parent::toArray($request);

        return [
            'data' => $this->collection->transform(function($comment){
                return [
                    'id' => $comment->id,
                    'comment' => $comment->comment,
                ];
            }),
        ];
    }
```

but the result will not include the `post_id` as key, how I can make it return the comments collection having key `post_id`?

**Update**

```
use App\models\Post;
use App\Http\Resources\Postas PostResource;

Route::get('/posts', function () {
    return PostResource::collection(Post::all()->keyBy->slug);
});
```

This is working correctly, but if I will use post collection inside User resource as relationship, it is not working! and that is my requirement in  comments collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did it, I created another ResourceGroupCollection class

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources\Collection;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class CommentGroupCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public $collects = 'App\Http\Resources\Collection\CommentCollection';

    public $preserveKeys = true;

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return $this->collection;
    }

}

<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources\Collection;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class CommentCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public $collects = 'App\Http\Resources\Comment';

    public $preserveKeys = true;

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return $this->collection;
    }

}

and then 

new CommentGroupCollection($comments->groupBy('post_id')),
```

Answer (score 0):

just like this :

```php
     public function toArray($request)
        {
            // return parent::toArray($request);

            return [
                'id' => $this->id,
                'name' => $this->name,
//                'comments' => $this->post->comments->keyBy('post_id')
                'comments' => new CommentCollection($this->post->comments)->keyBy('post_id')

            ];
        }
```

Comment: You can see, I have the exact code and it is not working, that is why I have posted the question.

Comment: Can you post you CommentCollection class ?

Comment: Not the toArray function(), it will not be used in your case, how is it constructed ? do you have a post_id column in it ? Can you dd(new CommentCollection($this->post->comments)); ?

Comment: I have some updates on my question, can you look into it, may be we will be having some clue.

Comment: I found a solution, and posted, may be you would like to check.